# How to read this particular file format?

Tags: python, file

I have the following text in a csv file:

`b'DataMart\n\nDate/Time Generated,11/7/16 8:54 PM\nReport Time Zone,America/New_York\nAccount ID,8967\nDate Range,10/8/16 - 11/6/16\n\nReport Fields\nSite (DCM),Creative\nGlobest.com,2016-08_CB_018_1040x320_Globe St_16_PropertyFilter\nGlobest.com,2016-08_CB_018_1040x320_Globe St_16_PropertyFilter'`

Essentially there are multiple new line characters in this file instead of a single big string so you can picture the same text as follows

```
DataMart
Date/Time Generated,11/7/16 8:54 PM
Report Time Zone,America/New_York
Account ID,8967
Date Range,10/8/16 - 11/6/16
Report Fields
Site (DCM),Creative
Globest.com,2016-08_CB_018_1040x320_Globe St_16_PropertyFilter
Globest.com,2016-08_CB_018_1040x320_Globe St_16_PropertyFilter
```

I need to grab the last two lines, which is basically the data. I tried doing a `for` loop:

```
with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

It instead prints the entire line again with `\n`.

Comment: You have a single byte string in a file?

Comment: yes it is a single byte string

Comment: You don't really have the standard format for a CSV. That was my main point

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `\n` at the end of the file? Also, what version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file and get the last two lines:

```
my_file = file("/path/to/file").read()
print(my_file.splitlines()[-2:])
```

The `[-2:]` is known as slicing: it creates a slice, starting from the second to last element, going to the end.

Comment: Could use `splitlines`?

Comment: Yes you could, I'll switch to that to make it more clear.

Comment: my_file=file("/pathtofile").read() gives me an error that file is not defined. Sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: @LucasVictor you need to replace that with the actual path to your file :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, after struggling around for a bit, i found out that i need to change the decoding of the file from binary to 'utf-8' and then i can apply the split functions. The problem was split functions are not applicable to the binary file.

This is the actual code that seems to be working for me now:

```
    with open('BinaryFile.csv','rb') as f1:
        data=f1.read()
        text=data.decode('utf-8')
        with open('TextFile.csv', 'w') as f2:
            f2.write(text)

    with open('TextFile.csv','r') as f3:
        for line in f3:
            print(line.split('\\n')[9:])
```

thanks for your help guys

Comment: You could also use the [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) function:
`import codecs   f = codecs.open("BinaryFile.csv", "rb", "utf-8")`